# Generalised coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, harmonic-oscillator, normal-modes

I am working on a scientific project for my university and I am reading a german paper (Karas: "Platten unter seitlichem Stoß") which makes use of generalised coordinates.

It's about an analytical solution of the impact of a ball on a plate.

At some point, he defines the potential energy for the plate $(a,b)$ as:

$$\tag{m,n = 1,2,3,...}V = ... \sum_m \sum_n q_{mn}^2 \left(\frac{m^2}{a^2} + \frac{n^2}{b^2} \right)^2$$

Aswell as the kinetic energy:

$$T = ... \sum_m \sum_n \dot{q}_{mn}^2$$

It doesnt explain what the $q$ stands for. It seems to be some kind of generalised coordinate but when looking for this on the web myself, I didnt find a good explanation.

So my question is:

> What does $q_{mn}$ mean? Why can $m,n$ be replaced with any positive number? How could I think about the coordinate as one on the plate? Does it equal the deflection?

Comment: Any links? Which page?

Comment: https://www.tib.eu/de/suchen/?tx_tibsearch_search%5Baction%5D=download&tx_tibsearch_search%5Bcontroller%5D=Download&tx_tibsearch_search%5Bdocid%5D=springer%3Adoi~10.1007%252FBF02084907&cHash=945a84f460e3b7f047cffa7e2ce3ccc8#download-mark

page 240

Comment: Requires login. Is there an abstract page?

Comment: you should be able to download without login (I did it aswell) (If you click on "Jetzt Laden" at the bottom of the page)

Comment: There is no such link on the page as it's displayed on my device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $q_{nm}$ are the amplitudes of the normal modes of vibration of the plate with sides $2\pi a$, $2\pi b$. He is using the usual plate wave equation 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}= D \left(\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^x}+\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial z^2}\right)^2
$$
and expanding the displacment as 
$$
y(x,y,t)= \sum_{n,m} q_{n,m}(t) \cos (mx/a)\cos (ny/b)
$$

Answer (score 2):

I think q here denotes a position coordinate. There exists a particular form of potential in which the dynamics of the ball work. It might be that, $q_{mn}$ determines the position of the $m^{\text{th}}$ particle of the ball w.r.t to the $n^{\text{th}}$ particle of the plate. At first, the total potential energy of the $m^{\text{th}}$ particle of the ball due to its interaction with each and every particle of the plate is calculated; that's how the $\sum_{n}$ comes. Next the potential energy of the entire ball is calculated by adding the potential energies of each such particle of the ball; this is how the $\sum_{m}$ comes. However, as both the ball and the plate have continuous mass distribution, the summations should be replaced by integrals.

${\dot q}_{mn}$ defines the velocity of the $m^{\text{th}}$ particle of the ball w.r.t the $n^{\text{th}}$ particle of the plate.  While calculating the kinetic energy, the summations appear following a similar argument as in the above paragraph and as it seems, they also should be replaced by integrals.

I do not know the exact context of your question though. This is as far as I got from it.

Comment: Mhm this would be one solution although it would also make sense that the m,n both corespond to both directions on the plate. Because the equation later ignores the ball and just replaces it with a time-dependent force.
I think this paper isnt well written because these things should be explained better...